# Constant integer trait in simple class

Tags: c++, type-traits

Given the following simple declaration, is it possible to give the class a constant integer trait specifying the number of components (2 in this case)?  Vec3 and Vec4 would have 3 and 4 respectively.  I just want this as a compile-time constant for instantiating other templates in various ways.  It doesn't have to be there at runtime.

```
template<class T>
struct Vec2
{ 
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef unsigned index_type;

    struct 
    {
        T x, y; 
    };
};
```

Comment: Do you want `Vec<2>`, `Vec<3>`...? Or `Vec2::num_components`, `Vec3::num_components`...? Maybe if you add the code that would make use of that trait, the question would be clearer.

Comment: I'd like Vec2::num_components if possible.

Comment: Just add `enum { num_components = 2 };` to the class. Would that be enough for you?

Comment: So if I had a template that accepts a T, I could still write T::num_components.  I feel a forehead slap moment coming on.

Comment: Yes, that is! Sometimes, C++ is easier than it looks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most portable way would be to add an enum constant:

```
template<class T> struct Vec2
{
    enum { num_components = 2 };
};
template<class T> struct Vec3
{
    enum { num_components = 3 };
};
```

Then just use `V::num_components` where needed.

If you are into C++11 then you can also use `static const int num_components = 2;` instead of an anonymous `enum`, but if you need compatibility with old compilers, then the `enum` idiom will save you some headaches.

Answer (score 2):

A solution would have you specifying **policies** to do exactly that

```
// base class to store members
template<size_t N>
struct Coords; 

template<>
struct Coords<2> {
    double x, y; 
}; 

template<>
struct Coords<3> {
    double x, y, z; 
}; 

template<>
struct Coords<4> {
    double x, y, z, w; 
}; 

// members depend on your base class
template<class T, size_t N>
struct Vec : Coords<N>
{
    using num = integral_constant<size_t, N>; 
};
```

Now the following exists per type (note that **`num` is a type so it doesn't occupy any space**) :

```
Vec<2> -> x, y        and   num::value = 2 (`constexpr` - compile time usable)        
Vec<3> -> x, y, z     and   num::value = 3              //  
Vec<4> -> x, y, z, w  and   num::value = 4              //
```

Unless you specifically want the **named members style** I'd suggest using a meber that contains all values, like

```
double _coords[N]; // N is a compile time constant so you can have arrays
```

because such a solution would be more scalable, generic and easier to code.

PS I'm using `double` in place of `T` to simplify the examples.

Comment: Could I replace struct with union, with anonymous structs inside to have the named members style and the array style together?  Or is this a very bad idea?

Comment: @Robinson This idea sounds like polymorphism in C. I can't know your criteria on what's a good idea; is this something that works better for you? In any case it's not my stlyle, so I wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to this problem in the standard library already.

`std::array<type, size>` is a fixed-size array of one type which has a size() member function, begin and end iterators plus an [] operator.

`std::tuple<types...>` gives vector of disjoint types which can be indexed by index: `get<i>(tuple)` or type `get<typename>(tuple)`.

edit:

here's one possible solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <array>

template<class Type, size_t Size>
struct my_vector
{
    static constexpr size_t num_components = Size;

    template<class...Args, typename = std::enable_if_t< (sizeof...(Args) == Size) > >
    my_vector(Args&&...args) : _data { std::forward<Args>(args)... } {}

    template<size_t I >
    Type get() const {
        return _data[I];
    }

    std::array<Type, Size> _data;
};

template<class Type, size_t Size, size_t I, class VectorType = my_vector<Type, Size>, typename = void>
struct get;
template<class Type, size_t Size, size_t I >
struct get<Type, Size, I, my_vector<Type, Size>, std::enable_if_t<I <= Size> >
{
static Type apply(const my_vector<Type, Size>& v) {
        return v.get<I>();
    }
};

template<class Type, size_t Size>
Type x(const my_vector<Type, Size>& v)
{
    return get<Type, Size, 0, my_vector<Type, Size>>::apply(v);
}

template<class Type, size_t Size>
Type y(const my_vector<Type, Size>& v)
{
    return get<Type, Size, 1, my_vector<Type, Size>>::apply(v);
}

template<class Type, size_t Size>
Type z(const my_vector<Type, Size>& v)
{
    return get<Type, Size, 2, my_vector<Type, Size>>::apply(v);
}

template<size_t I, class Type, size_t Size>
Type more(const my_vector<Type, Size>& v)
{
    return get<Type, Size, I+3, my_vector<Type, Size>>::apply(v);
}


template<class T> using Vec2 = my_vector<T, 2>;
template<class T> using Vec3 = my_vector<T, 3>;
template<class T> using Vec6 = my_vector<T, 6>;

using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    Vec2<int> v2 { 1, 2 };
    Vec3<int> v3 { 1, 2, 3 };
    Vec6<int> v6 { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    cout << "v2: " << x(v2) << ", " << y(v2) << endl;
    cout << "v3: " << x(v3) << ", " << y(v3) << ", " << z(v3) << endl;
    cout << "v6: "
    << x(v6) << ", " << y(v6) << ", " << z(v6) << ", "
    << more<0>(v6) << ", " << more<1>(v6) << ", " << more<2>(v6)
    << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
v2: 1, 2
v3: 1, 2, 3
v6: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Comment: I thought about tuple but didn't think about std::array. At the moment I've got a union however (not quite the same as the example), so I can reference them as .x, .y or [0][1] or for vec4, a vec3 and a single float, etc.  This is useful in some cases.

Comment: @Robinson added a little example.

Comment: I'll study that, thanks.  Unfortunately I don't get constexpr until Visual studio 2015 ships so I won't be able to compile it at the moment.

Comment: replace it with `enum { num_components = Size; }`. Good enough.